# How to fix the NavbarCollapse class from appending to my URLs

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a customized version of the PIXMA template for wordpress (from wrapboostrap) and I noticed that in webmaster tools I'm getting errors for the `.navbar-collapse` class being appended to our URL. At the moment, here is the line of code that's displaying our mobile menu:

```
<!-- Mobile Menu Start -->
<div class="mobile navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href=".navbar-collapse">
   <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
   </a> 
</div>
<!-- Mobile Menu End -->
```

I've tried to just put a "#" in the href to avoid this issue but then it just breaks the functionality of the navbar on mobile devices. Anyone have some advice on how to fix this? The URL on my blog posts look like this:

```
cctv-security-surveillance-articles/monitor-employees/.navbar-collapse
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the href to data-target like so:

```
<!-- Mobile Menu Start -->
<div class="mobile navbar-header">
   <a class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
   <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
   </a> 
</div>
<!-- Mobile Menu End -->
```

Comment: This seems to have fixed the issue. It also pushed me to look up the data tags and I got to learn something new. Thanks! I'll come back here if this ever poses any other issues. I appreciate the help.